# Map same key twice : Auto Hotkey

Tags: autohotkey, keymapping

Is there any way to map a key twice using AHK?
My code is the following:

```
loop
{
    GetKeyState, state, Alt
    if state = U
    {
        RButton::t
    }
    else
    {
        RButton::RButton
    }
}
```

I get an error "Error: Duplicate hotkey" for trying to map twice my RButton.

What I wanna do here is pretty simple ; I want my RButton to become 't' when 'alt' is not pressed and I want it back to RButton when 'alt' is pressed.

Thank you

Edit:
I don't want:

```
!RButton::t
```

I want:

```
RButton::t
!RButton::RButton
```

But it is not working either.

Comment: That last example is working for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36175810/3779853 might be interesting for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exactly

```
RButton::t
!RButton::RButton
```

should actually work, not sure why it doesn't.

Anway,

```
RButton::
    send t
return

!RButton::
    click right
return
```

works.