# Make Shortcut key to work only if Windows Explorer is open in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I have a requirement of opening my application using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  within Windows Explorer. I think I can implement this using Auto hot key.

```
WinWait, Windows Explorer
{
^f::
    Run "C:\myapp.exe"
    return
}
```

But the code is not working. The code opens my application even if Windows Explorer is not open. I want  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  to be open my application only if it is active in front. I dont want to open my application even if Windows Explorer is minimized.

How can I achieve this ?

Is there any other techniques to achieve the same ?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36175810/3779853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #IfWin directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys. Such hotkeys perform a different action depending on the type of window that is active or exists.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass

^f::
Run "C:\myapp.exe"
return

#IfWinActive  ; turn off context sensitivity
```

The class name of a window identifies what type of window it is.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class