# AHK WinActive not recognizing window

Tags: window, autohotkey, detection

I'm trying to make a hotkey available to only a sub-window (or toolbox-stlye-window) of Reaper.

Using this "tutorial" on AHK #If and If:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175810/7863776

I got this far:

```
#If (WinActive("Plug-in pin connector"))
^Space::
    Click
    MouseMove, 16, 16, 0, R
    Click
    MouseMove, 16, 16, 0, R
Return
#If
```

When I use the hotkey after clicking into the correct window, the keypress isn't caught by AHK. Doing this with the hotkey outside an If, AHK catches the hotkey but nothing happens. This leads me to believe WinActive isn't seeing the window, while Windowspy clearly does.

These also don't help:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
DetectHiddenWindows, On
```

Windowspy shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeuj.png)

The only sure way to make this hotkey exclusive to that window is with the title "Plug-in pin connector", though neither "ahk_exe reaper.exe", nor "ahk_class #32770" work. I'd be happy if they did.
AHK is running as admin.

Comment: You seem to have covered all the bases. I see you've tried `SetTitleMatchMode, 2`, but have you tried it with a smaller portion of the title, such as just `connector`? Also, ACC viewer might reveal more details than Window Spy that might shed light on the issue. https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=26201

Comment: Thank you Evan, didn't know of ACCviewer but it's telling me the same thing.

Comment: Thank you Evan, didn't know of ACCviewer but it's telling me the same [thing](http://img110.xooimage.com/files/3/e/3/io_accviewer-55cbc52.png). I tried `WinActive("ahk_exe reaper.exe","connector")` and `WinActive("connector")` with TitleMatchMode 2 but no dice.

Comment: Interestingly, WinTitle is blank but has WinText that matches your apparent title.

Comment: and class and process are empty, how interesting... I wonder if I left the WinTitle of WinActive empty and just used "connector" in the WinText field... but `WinActive(,"connector")` sadly doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discoveries with ACC viewer, please see if this works for you:

```
^Space::
WinGetText , sWinText , A
If InStr( sWinText , "Plug-in pin connector" )
    MsgBox , It worked!
Else
    MsgBox , It didn't work....`n`nHere's what was found: %sWinText%
Return
```

**Edit:** As found by OP in comments below, `ControlGetText` can be used to detect whether the "Plug-in pin connector" window is active.

Comment: with the `$` the key doesn't get caught by AHK, without it AHK at least catches the hotkey keystroke but sadly still nothing

Comment: The `$` is just so that it doesn't trigger itself in the else-condition. Perhaps change what happens in the else-condition to show what is found. I'll edit the code above for that purpose.

Comment: I'm stumped then. Are you triggering the hotkey with "Plug-in pin connector" window active?

Comment: yes, after clicking inside it once...maybe ACCviewer fetches the "Text: " field differently than WinGetText? Because it is present, WinGetText just can't see it...And the "Text:" field of ACCviewer keeps displaying "Plug-in pin connector" no matter where I point it inside that little window...

Comment: So I looked at the ACCviewer code and it uses two methods: WinGetText and ControlGetText. When I insert that into your code, and add a comma, I get an "it works!" horaay!!! Didn't think I was smart enough to read the ACCviewer source but somehow I lucked out! Thank you Evan!!!

Comment: changed the line to `ControlGetText , sWinText ,, A`

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works! I was also looking through the ACC source code and it really starts with the `MouseGetPos, , , Whwnd` at line 327, but it has so many custom functions and DllCalls that I got lost pretty quick.